# Altering 10% of Values in Dictionary Comprehension using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension, for-comprehension

I am having an issue making a dictionary comprehension. I have made list comprehensions before, and thought they'd be similar, but with `{}` instead.

I am pretty sure my `random` logic is sound, for the task I want though.

Updated dict:

```
import random

DLM = '~'  # deliminator

programmatic_dict = {
  "brand~test": "Ford",
  "model~test": "Mustang",
  "year~test": "2019"
}
print(programmatic_dict)

programmatic_dict = {programmatic_dict[key]: val + DLM + key.rsplit(DLM, 1)[1] else val for key, val in programmatic_dict.items() if random.randint(0,9) == 9}
print(programmatic_dict)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 144, in compile
    code = loader.source_to_code(source_bytes, dfile or file,
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./prog.py", line 13
    programmatic_dict = {programmatic_dict[key]: val + DLM + key.rsplit(DLM, 1)[1] else val for key, val in programmatic_dict.items() if random.randint(0,2) == 2}
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 150, in compile
    raise py_exc
py_compile.PyCompileError:   File "./prog.py", line 13
    programmatic_dict = {programmatic_dict[key]: val + DLM + key.rsplit(DLM, 1)[1] else val for key, val in programmatic_dict.items() if random.randint(0,2) == 2}
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Desired Output:

```
programmatic_dict = {
  "brand~test": "Ford",
  "model~test": "Mustang~test",  # subtag in key string, added randomly at 10% (unlikely)
  "year~test": "2019"
}
```

**Where am I going wrong on my dictionary comprehension code line?**

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post to help further clarify (as I know it's a strange task what I'm wanting done).

Comment: Try `programmatic_dict[x]: val` in your dict comprehension

Comment: Note that the logic is wrong, this will not alter the values 10% of the time. It will actually shrink (essentially delete) key, value pairs 90% of the time

Comment: `programmatic_dict[key]:` Does it, how do I add an else statement of just `val`?

Comment: @DeepSpace Oh flip, thank you

Comment: I've added an else statement to remove that possibility, check post

Comment: But `random.randint(0,2) == 2` will be True 33% of times, not 10%

Comment: Sorry, that was for my own experimental purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Amendments:

- reference any key as `key:`,
- else statement of `else val`, for the 90% of the time I didn't want any change to my value.

```
programmatic_dict = {key: val + DLM + key.rsplit(DLM, 1)[1] if random.randint(0, 9) == 9 else val for key, val in programmatic_dict.items()}
```

[Article](https://pythonguides.com/python-dictionary-comprehension/#:%7E:text=In%20this%20case%2C%20a%20new%20original%20dictionary%20is,condition%20is%20true%20then%20%E2%80%98else%E2%80%99%20statement%20will%20execute.) Ctrl+F: "Python dictionary comprehension if else"

Comment: Note: I need to wait 48HRS to accept answer